# NPrinting Error (Qlikview) - Access Violation at address 0040A3EF

Tags: qlikview

Hitting an error when running my nPrinting On-Demand reports.

No changes were made to the software but just has stopped working.

I have been passed on this software with minimal instructions so I'm not sure if I'm missing plug-ins (For example I can't see the Queue dropdown bit when I open QV Desktop)

Does anyone know how to resolve the error as causing quite a few issues since users can't obtain reports.

[image]

Thank you,
Craig

```
Unexpected error occured during On-Demand request processing. Access violation at address 0040A3EF in Module 'NPrintingSvc.exe'. Read of address 00000000
```

craig157_0-1599058681999.png

Running on NPrinting 16.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have found a solution but it might not be related!

So when I run the button I am sending a 'Customer Name' parameter through.

In this instance our customer name contained a forward slash character "Example Company T/A Blahblah Ltd"

When we removed the special character the reports were running fine again with no errors.